# How to restore postgresql databases after resetting my server

Tags: postgresql, restore, tablespace

I recently completely re-installed my server and I am struggling with restoring the database I had before.
Previously, I saved my database into different HDD using tablespace, so I have db located in that HDD. (saved file path looks like: "**/{HDD_directory}/PG_10_201707211/16385"**)
For the main postgres folder, I installed in the previous system in different drive so unfortunately I can't recover the main folder previously using.

So after I re-installed my server and postgresql, I tried to bring back my db by copying the **16385** folder to "/var/lib.postgres/main/base".
But psql do not recognize the db. (I guess it is because the configurations are different?)
I tried to find a solution but all I could find was restoring using pg_restore command, which requires pg_dump and backup file. But I don't have a backup file (I have only db directory **16385**).

I am using ubuntu OS and postgres version 12.
Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: you need to post the commands you entered and the errors that you received.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So the command I entered is **mv {previously_saved_db_folder} /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/base**. And there is no error. I simply cannot just read my db from psql.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the tablespace files alone are not enough to reattach it to a database. Here's a warning from the [tablespace section of the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) that explains it:

> Even though located outside the main PostgreSQL data directory, tablespaces are an integral part of the database cluster and cannot be treated as an autonomous collection of data files. They are dependent on metadata contained in the main data directory, and therefore cannot be attached to a different database cluster or backed up individually. Similarly, if you lose a tablespace (file deletion, disk failure, etc), the database cluster might become unreadable or unable to start. Placing a tablespace on a temporary file system like a RAM disk risks the reliability of the entire cluster.

Comment: Wow.... I didn't know about this. No wonder why I couldn't find the solution on internet.
Then, is it possible to see what's in the db folder using postgresql or any other tools? Only I can see from the folder is some files named numbers and other unreadable files.

Comment: The information required to make something out of tablespace files - making them make sense as database objects - was in the system catalog, unfortunately. If everything except tablespace files was truly lost, at this point it's more of a data **reconstruction** task than a data **recovery** one. There are no official tools as officially PostgreSQL does not support this type of [selective file system level backups](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/backup-file.html).